# How can I display object property's property value in react?

Tags: reactjs, object

How can I display object property's property value in react?

like this below

```
Temperature: {
  Metric: {
    Value: 27.8,
    Unit: "C",
    UnitType: 17
  },
  Imperial: {
    Value: 82,
    Unit: "F",
    UnitType: 18
  }
};
```

I want to write on  just metric's value : 27.8

I wrote this code below but I got error.

```
import React from "react";
import Cities from "./Cities";

const CityList = ({ cities }) => {
  const cityArray = cities.map((user, i) => {
    return (
      <Cities
        key={user[i].Key}
        WeatherText={user[i].WeatherText}
        EnglishName={user[i].EnglishName}
        Value={user[i].Temperature.Metric.Value}
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="tc">
      <div> {cityArray} </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CityList;
```

thanks

Comment: whats the error? Also, `use backticks` (`) to mark text as code.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What error? From where `user` is coming from?

Comment: here is the code

import React from 'react';
import Cities from './Cities';

const CityList = ({cities})=>{
 const cityArray = cities.map((user,i) => {
  return (
   <Cities 
    key={user[i].Key} 
    WeatherText={user[i].WeatherText} 
    EnglishName={user[i].EnglishName}
    Value={user[i].Temperature.Metric.Value}
    />
  );  
 });
 return (
 <div className='tc'>
  <div>
   {cityArray}
  </div> 
 </div>
 );
}
export default CityList;

Comment: You misunderstood how `.map()` works.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Can you add what do you get in props.cities?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
const CityList = ({ cities }) => {
  const cityArray = cities.map((city) => {
    return (
      <Cities
        key={city.Key}
        WeatherText={city.WeatherText}
        EnglishName={city.EnglishName}
        Value={city.Temperature.Metric.Value}
      />
    );
  });
```

Also, variables should not start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: when i type like your answer  i get .map() is not function error

Comment: Then you are missing more info in your original post. Please expand.